# count values in multiple columns mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table that contains user submitted answers to 3 questions. all the answers to the questions are yes/no answers. Like so

```
username        question1          question2         question3

user1           yes                no                yes
user2           yes                yes               yes
user3           yes                no                no
user4           no                 no                no
```

What I want to do is collect the count of each 'yes' in each column. So I would have the amount of yes's for each question ie 'question1' = '3', question2 = '1' etc etc.

At the moment I have 3 separate statements for each question which works fine but I was just wondering if there is a way to combine these into one statement to make it more effective?

Comment: can you post your sql statements to let us see what to combine?

Comment: if you would have used int values (and not strings that can create problems), let's say 1 for yes, 0 for no you could have used a sum on each column

Comment: In theory I think it might be possible but i suspect it would require a lot of self-joining and Unions to do.

Comment: It's best (or at least better) practice to store boolean values as TINYINT (0 for no, 1 for yes).

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with a simple aggregate `SUM()` (with no `GROUP BY`) surrounding a `CASE` statement.  If the value is `yes`, it returns a 1, and otherwise a 0.  Those 1's are then added over the column via `SUM()`.

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE WHEN question1 = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS q1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN question2 = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS q2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN question3 = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS q3
FROM yourtable
```

MySQL will also permit a simple boolean comparison which returns 1 or 0,  but this is not portable to other RDBMS.

```
/* Shorter version, only works for MySQL */
SELECT 
  SUM(question1 = 'yes') AS q1,
  SUM(question2 = 'yes') AS q2,
  SUM(question3 = 'yes') AS q3
FROM yourtable
```